# Besides POSIX what other standards are published by IEEE?

Tags: standards, ieee

As I have understood, IEEE is responsible for standardizing computer practices and POSIX is one of the standards issued by IEEE.

I wish to know what are some other standards issued by IEEE? Is there a list somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have at it.](http://standards.ieee.org)

The IEEE is the *Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers*. They have promulgated several standards related to computer programming- like IEEE 754 floating point arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

The first one that comes to mind is the standard for floating point arithmetic behavior.
A more comprehensive list is available on Wikipeda [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_Standards_Association#Notable_IEEE_Standards_committees_and_formats)

Comment: thankful to you. I did look at wikipedia but couldn't find anything.